# Moving a web methods folder into webMethods?

Tags: webmethods

I had to switch computers at work and my WEBMethods project was not moved to the new computer. After installing WEBMethods we noticed that my project had not been copied over.

So I went in to the laptop and found the folder that contains the webmethods project. 
I copied all of the files in that folder along with the folder name to my new computer.

I know want to import that directory to WEBMethods (I noticed WEBMethods stores all of the information in a huge, huge XML file)

This is the folder that contains all of my files for this specific project.

**Question: How can I get it moved into WEBMethods?**

[image]

Comment: Is it just a service package or it includes CAF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy way to move your package:

1) Login to the webMethods administrative web console

2) Navigate to `Packages > Management`. You'll see a list of all the packages on your integration server.

3) Identify the packages related to your project and for each package click on [image]

4) On the "Archive" setup page, leave everything as is except for the archive name. Name it to something you'll easily recognize.

5) At the bottom of the "Archive" setup page, click on the "Create Archive" button. This will create a zip file in the following folder

```
IntegrationServer\replicate\outbound
```

6) Copy the zip file to the new computer at the following location:

```
IntegrationServer\replicate\inbound
```

7) In the webMEthods administrative web console of the new computer, navigate to `Packages > Management` and click on the "Install Inbound Releases" link.

8) Select the zip file in the select box

9) Click on "Install release".

Comment: As a side note, teams usually use webMethods Deployer for release management. There's also a third party release management and source control tool called CrossVista.

Answer (score 2):

While copying packages it is always recommended to export the package and load it to new location. You can either use the Administrator Page to get the package or in  case if you dont have Administrator access, then in that case you can use your developer/ designer to get the package. Follow below steps:

1. Select the package you want to move.
2. For Developer, click on File Menu(top left corner)>Export option to save the package on your current system.
3. For Designer, right click on the package you want to move. Select Export from Server option and save the package on your current system.
4. The package is now saved as a ZIP file. Copy the ZIP file to the new system.
5. In your new system, place the ZIP file to- IntegrationServer\replicate\inbound folder.
6. Open webMethods Administrator page and Select Packages>Management option. Click on Install inbound Releases Link.
7. Select the package name from dropdown and click on Install release.

In case you dont have Administrator access, you can pass the zip file to the person who has the access and they can follow the steps 5 to 7

If your package exists on an accessible server(A server you can login from your current machine), then open the server session in which the package exists. Also open the server where you want to place the package in the same Developer/designer. Using this way you can simply copy the package from one server and paste to other.
But while using this, make sure that dependent packages if any, exists in the target server.

Answer (score 2):

Its always better , if you create the Release. Go to Publish link and create the full Build or patch.whatever you want, add the subscription to it and send it to remotes system via clicking send release link.